Assets dont load when angular app is localized
i am trying to create a website for myself where one can change the language. I followed the Angular's documentation on locales (link) step by step. I marked my HTML elements with the i18n tag, extracted a messages.xlf file, added the translation myself and configured angular.json as following:
"projects": {
  "Frontend": {
    "i18n": {
      "sourceLocale": "de",
      "locales": {
        "en": {
          "translation": "src/locale/messages.en.xlf",
          "baseHref": "en/"
        }
      }
    },
    ......
    "architect": {
      "build": {
        .....
        "options": {
          "localize": true,
         .............
        }
        .......
        "assets": [
          {
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "public"
          }
        ],

if you replace "localize" with an element like "en" or "de", run with ng serve, the website loads correctly with the translation. if i specify "localize": true, build the project with ng build --localize, then run serve ./dist/frontend/browser, i see this when i load the local host:

navigating into either "de/" or "en/", the website loads with the correct translation, but any image asset inside public/assets/images/ return a 404 error. i think this is because it actually now has the path <locale>/assets/images/ instead of /assets/images/. if i type for example http://localhost:3000/de/assets/images/myimage.jpg it correctly retrieves the image. how do i configure angular so it requests images from the locale-specific route? i would appreciate the help!

How is your base href configured in index.html? What is the exact path of the image that you tried to use?

@JSONDerulo i have not configured anything in index.html. but i just took a look: by default it was <base href="/">. I removed that line completely and i still get the same behaviour. The exact path in to image is /assets/images/myimage.jpg

You must not prefix asset paths with /. The image will then be loaded from the server root and not from the application's base URL. For applications with i18n and multiple locales this is particularly important as the application does not run on root. Just skip the leading / and the assets will load correctly.
<img src="assets/images/myimage.jpg">


This worked! but now i have another problem: i have a css class with background-image: url("/assets/images/myimage.jpg") , when i remove the prefix, i get this error when serving or building: Could not resolve "assets/images/myimage.jpg". do you know why this is different than the  element?

URLs in CSS are handled differently. AFAIK they are inlined, meaning the path of the image is evaluated at build time. This is in contrast to the img paths, which are evaluated at runtime.

Alright thank you for the input. i managed to work-around this by inlining a style="background-image:...." in the HTML element. this solved the problem. I appreciate your help!
